# Анимация при клике через v-if?

Tags: vue.js

Как реализовать плавную анимация при клике (

```js
data() {
      return {
        show: false,
        };
        },
        methods: [
toggleShow(){
        this.show = !this.show;
      },
      }
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.item {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, height 0.3s 0.1s;
}

.active .item {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 30px;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0.1s, height 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<Button @click="toggleShow()">Show</Button>
    <div v-if="show" :class="{'active':show}">
      <p class="red item">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo, accusantium!
      </p>
    </div>
```

появления блока)

Comment: Вроде уже реализовано - осталось убрать `v-if`, оставив только бинд на `class`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6t4u9Lwg/
  осталось только плавно закрывать блок

Answer (score 0):

Заберите `v-if` и додайте клас `item` вместо `v-if`